# What is wrong with my MATLAB code? (Beginner here)

Tags: matlab

Function 1:

```
  function [x,y]=func1(x,y)
      x = input('Enter how many tickets you would like: ');
      y = input('Enter what level you would like to sit in: ');
  end
```

Function 2:

```
  function [z] = func2(x,y)
  switch l
      case y==1
       z = 500*x;


  case y==2
   z = 350*x;

  case y==3
   z = 200*x;


end
```

Function 3:

```
  function [x,y,z]=func3(x,y,z)
  [x,y]=func1(x,y);
  z=func2(x,y);
  fprintf('It will cost $%.2f for %d tickets in level %d.','z','x','y');
  end
```

I'd like to call upon these three functions in succession (this is how I tried to do it):

```
  func1(x,y)
  func2(x,y)
  func3(x,y,z)
```

I'd like for only three lines to be printed (except I want the actual calculation to be printed rather than x,y,z):

```
  Enter how many tickets you would like:
  Enter what level you would like to sit in:
  It will cost $z for x tickets in level y.
```

The first of these two lines come out fine, but the third prints random numbers in place of x,y,z. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read manual about `switch - case` construction - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html `case y==1` is incorrect, as the case value should be equal to the value of the variable used in `switch` statement. And you do not have variable `l` there.

Answer (score 3):

Your `fprintf` statement should be

```
fprintf('It will cost $%.2f for %d tickets in level %d.',z,x,y);
```

you want the values stored in `x, y, z`, not the strings `'x', 'y', 'z'`.